# Styling anchor and li elements css

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a progress bar. It works well, but my concern is for the style. Some lines are displayed and I don't know why. In the screenshot below you can see lines between numbers. Any ideas?

[image: Screenshot]

**My jsfiddle:** [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/aLwgrym8/61/embedded/result/)

**My code:**

```css
ol.progtrckr {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
}

ol.progtrckr li {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 3em;
}

ol.progtrckr[data-progtrckr-steps="4"] li { width: 15%; }

ol.progtrckr li.progtrckr-done {
    color: black;
    padding-right: 12px;
    border-bottom: 4px solid green;
}
ol.progtrckr li.progtrckr-todo {
    color: silver; 
    padding-right: 12px;
    border-bottom: 4px solid silver;
}

ol.progtrckr li:after {
    content: "\00a0\00a0";
}
ol.progtrckr li:before {
    position: relative;
    bottom: -2.5em;
    float: left;
    left: 50%;
    line-height: 1em;
}
ol.progtrckr li.progtrckr-done:before {
    content: "\2713";
    color: white;
    background-color: green;
    height: 1.2em;
    width: 1.2em;
    line-height: 1.2em;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 1.2em;
}
ol.progtrckr li.progtrckr-todo:before {
    content: "\039F";
    color: silver;
    background-color: white;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    bottom: -1.6em;
}
```

```html
<ol class="progtrckr" data-progtrckr-steps="">
    <a href="#" >
    <li class="progtrckr-done ">1 </li> </a>
    <a href="#">
    <li  class="progtrckr-done">2 </li> </a>
    <a href="#">
    <li class="progtrckr-done">3 </li> </a>
    <a href="#">
    <li class="progtrckr-todo">4 </li> </a>
  
</ol>
```

Comment: did you try below given solution?

Comment: try ol.progtrckr>a {text-decoration:none !important;}

Comment: `li` is the only allowed descendant element of both `ol` and `ul` elements and the only possible parent of the former are the latter. Even if HTML5 allows for elements like h1 or p into an `a` element, it's still impossible for `li`

Comment: @EgzontinaK It is normally expected for the OP to provide feedback on the answers provided to their question. If any of the answers helped you should consider upvoting them and if one in particular assisted you you should mark it as accepted. If none of the answers currently fix your problem you should expand and clarify your original question.

Answer (score 3):

Please apply text-decoration:none for anchor under  with class "progtrckr" this line will be disappear or add below css in your stylesheet file -

```
ol.progtrckr>a {
text-decoration:none;
}
```

Comment: text-decoration:none; don't solve  my problem, i tired this before!

Comment: Ok do one thing an try like this ol.progtrckr>a {text-decoration:none !important;} I think this will solve the issue try and let me know because I am 1005 sure this issue is because of text-decoration only

Answer (score 2):

You using "display: inline-block" for "ol.progtrckr li", so these elements behave like inline elements but they have the space. So you should use "float:left" instead of "display: inline-block". You also should use "clearfix" for "ol" element. For example: add ".clerfix" class to "ol" element and use the following css:

```
.clearfix:after {
content: ".";3
display: block;
height: 0;
clear: both;
visibility: hidden;
}
```

Comment: +1 but you can also remove whitespace (the one causing this 4px gap) right into the HTML code and still use inline-block without this dreaded whitespace. Example: `</li><li>`. Other method: not closing the `</li>`

Answer (score 1):

You have to put your "li" tags before your "a" tags, like this:

```
<ol class="progtrckr" data-progtrckr-steps="">
    <li class="progtrckr-done"><a href="#">1</a></li>
    <li class="progtrckr-done"><a href="#">2</a></li>
    <li class="progtrckr-done"><a href="#">3</a></li>
    <li class="progtrckr-done"><a href="#">4</a></li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are linking the entire `<li>` element while you should link only the value inside it:

```
<ol class="progtrckr" data-progtrckr-steps="">
   <li class="progtrckr-done "><a href="#" >1</a></li>
   <li class="progtrckr-done "><a href="#" >2</a></li>
   <li class="progtrckr-done "><a href="#" >3</a></li>
   <li class="progtrckr-done "><a href="#" >4</a></li> 
</ol>
```

Here is the updated [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o4qqnukr/) I also added a `padding:0` here:

```
ol.progtrckr li.progtrckr-done {
    color: black;
    padding-right: 12px;
    border-bottom: 4px solid green;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's default text decoration on the `<a>` element.

Use:

```
a{
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
a:link {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

(Links are underlined by default in many browsers)

Addition: Or, if you want to keep the underline in your regular links, write this instead, and to be safe, include the other link states too:

```
.progtrckr-done a:link,
.progtrckr-done a:hover,
.progtrckr-done a:active,
.progtrckr-done a:visited {
   text-decoration: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Updated fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/aLwgrym8/63/

You simply need to add text-decoration: none to the anchor elements:

```
ol.progtrckr > a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

Alternatively, you could move the anchor elements within the `<li>`'s as opposed to the other way around which you're currently doing. Updated fiddle for this here: https://jsfiddle.net/aLwgrym8/65/

**HTML:**

```
<ol class="progtrckr" data-progtrckr-steps="">
    <li class="progtrckr-done "><a href="#" >1</a></li> 
    <li  class="progtrckr-done"><a href="#">2</a></li> 
    <li class="progtrckr-done"><a href="#">3</a></li> 
    <li class="progtrckr-todo"><a href="#">4</a></li>
</ol>
```

**CSS:**

```
ol.progtrckr li > a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that you have spaces between your closing `</li>`tags and the closing `</a>`tags.

```
<li  class="progtrckr-done">2 </li> </a>
```

If you remove these, all the above actions won't be necessary at all, because there's nothing to underline in the links.